# Calculating the wavelength of vibrations of a material

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, wavelength, vibrations, solid-mechanics

I am curious about how you would calculate the *wavelength range* (the actual wavelength for the particles moving back and forth from their form equilibrium position) for particles vibrating in a solid material. The vibrations would be caused by a phonon.

I cannot find the wavelength range for particles vibrating in a solid material anywhere online, or the calculation. It seems to me that the wavelength would be pretty small, something down to the order of micrometers for a solid (or smaller).

How would you perform this calculation? Would you use statistical mechanics for this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the "wavelength range"  Do you mean the actual wavelength, its uncertainty, or the amplitude of the motion? And do you mean in a typical sound wave, or in thermal motion?  There are too many possibilities....

Comment: @mikestone I updated my question to include these details. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Look up the Debeye model for specific heats.

Comment: Are you asking about wavelengths or frequencies? They would be different questions with different answers.

Comment: @GiorgioP I am asking about wavelengths, not frequencies.

Comment: @Tachyon you're asking about de Broglie wavelengths of *particles* or wavelengths of elastic vibrations of the *material* (which consists of many particles, and where the wavelength has different meaning)?

Comment: @RogerVadim The check-marked answer has got it correct. I was looking for elastic vibrations of the individual particles within a solid material when there is a phonon present. Nothing Quantum Mechanical.

Comment: @Tachyon then it is not correct to describe them by a *wave length* - it is not a property of a single particle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum wavenumber in the Brillouin zone is $k=\pi/a$ where $a$ is the lattice constant. This corresponds to a wavelength of $\lambda = 2a$. Typical lattice constants are about $4\cdot10^{-10}\,$m. So the wavelenghts would be on the order of a couple Angström.  If you're referring to the amplitude then I don't know the answer.

Comment: That's the lower limit for the wavelength. You should add that, for an infinite system, there is no upper limit. (The OP was asking for a *range*).

Comment: Yes, if you could do that, it would be good. But I have a rough idea of what the approximate range is from the Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_constant.